# Как выковырять html разметку?

Tags: php, html, css

Добрый день уважаемые. Я начинающий разработчик. Столкнулся с такой задачей. На данной странице сейчас отображается 2 модуля бронирования (в коде можно посмотреть, как они разграничиваются). Нужно, чтобы десктопный модуль отображался только для десктопа (начиная с разрешения, когда хедр становится полноценным), а мобильный, начиная с разрешения, когда появляется мобильный хедр. Как это реализовать по средствам HTML и CSS я знаю, но в полученных с сервера данных я увидел только php файлы. Как мне найти куда впиливать код? 
Сайт прилагается https://fex.net/#!052288218178

К каким файлам надо обращаться ? 
[image: mobile]
[image: desctop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не уверен, что полностью понял и осознал вопрос.
Если вопрос звучит: "Как мне найти куда впиливать код?" - то, логически рассуждая, если вы не можете повлиять на HTML-разметку данных со стороннего сервера, вы можете повлиять на ее отображение внутри iframe средствами CSS на своей стороне.

Как это делается, описано в английской версии - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Сложно сказать что-либо точнее на основе вашего вопроса, непонятно, к каким файлам у вас имеется доступ.

Comment: Доступ ко всем данным которые находятся на сервере (ну или мне так кажется) (собственно  это они и есть) по крайней мере те что мне удалось скачать через WinSCP. Но я совершенно не могу найти где здесь то что отвечает за данный фрейм

Comment: вы хотите повлиять на iframe с сылкой на e-hostel-book.otelms.com - если это ваш сайт - то воспользуйтесь поиском по файлу, если это не ваш сайт, то вы НИЧЕГО не сможете сделать, только лишь изменить размеры самого iframe. В настоящее время iframe устарел. Сейчас пользуются api.